# PHP log in validate

Tags: php

The constants just contains the database connection details

```
require_once 'includes/constants.php';
class mysql{
    private $conn;

    function __construct(){
        $this->conn = $conn = new MySQLi(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
            or die ('There was an error in the connection');
        }

    function verify ($un, $pwd){


             $query = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ? AND pass = ? LIMIT 1"; 

             if ($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query))
             {
                 $stmt->bind_param('ss', $un, $pwd);
                 $stmt->execute();

                 if ($stmt->fetch());{
                     $stmt->close();
                     return true;
                     }
             }
        }

    }

?>
```

un and pwd have been passed through from login page , they are extracted from the user input, the problem I'm having is the user is always logged in no matter what they enter, it doesn't seem to validating correctly against database

Comment: How are you calling the verify method? Why does it not return false? Also the ; after the inner if-statement seems to be misplaced.

Comment: The semi colon after if statement is valid? if ($stmt->fetch());

Comment: Actual data gathering is best left out of OOP Scope, instead you should study a MySQLI Wrapper to make your queries easier. Call your wrapper queries and validate the results from that. #

Comment: @user2071225 If you're formatting code, at least leave the bug in.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to do that!

Comment: What IDE are you using? I think any code parsing equipped IDE should have picked up on that.

Comment: @Technoh Well, it's not *invalid code* per se... IDEA doesn't pick up on it for one.

Comment: @deceze You are absolutely right, I should have tested it before commenting! Surprising as I don't see the point of having `{}` nested blocks free in the code (e.g. without a condition/loop/etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
if ($stmt->fetch());{
   $stmt->close();
   return true;
}
```

to

```
 if ($stmt->fetch()){
   $stmt->close();
   return true;
}else
{ return false;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($stmt->fetch());{
                   ^------- THIS!
    $stmt->close();
    return true;
}
```

This `if` is followed by an *empty statement*, after which comes a new block `{...}` of statements. The `if` is only associated with the empty statement, so the following block is always executed.

To illustrate:

```
if (false)
    /* do nothing */;

{
    echo 'always goes here';
}
```

Get rid of the superfluous `;`.